# Pipelight not working on netflix

Tags: 14.04, netflix, drm, pipelight

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed pipelight by following [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html) and switched my user agent.  And I can run [this test](http://bubblemark.com/silverlight2.html) just fine.  The problem is that Netflix still gives me a DRM error number N8156-6023. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: it's Firefox 30.

Comment: If you make that a solution, and mark it as a solution, I'll upvote that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me.  I checked the the [pipelight FAQ](https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faqs) and disabled HTTPS Everywhere and it worked.

Comment: Worked, but still no 1080p. Also v-sync is not working, seeing flickr with native Intel drivers. Will switch back to other sources that are reliable. Netflix need to deliver full support for Linux. How hard can it be?

Comment: Netflix works on chrome for linux now.